# Integration homework help

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

how would I go about integrating this?

$$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin x}{1+x^2}dx$$

Comment: The function is odd.

Comment: I don’t know what that means

Comment: It means $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about odd functions - functions where $-o(-x) = o(x)$. One of the many interesting things about these functions is that sometimes we can simplify their integrals:

$$\int_{-c}^c o(x)dx = \int^0_{-c}o(x)dx + \int_0^c o(x)dx = \int^0_{-c}-o(-x) + \int_0^c o(x)dx = \int^0_{c}o(x) + \int_0^c o(x)dx = -\int_0^c o(x)dx + \int_0^c o(x)dx = 0$$

Intuitively, everything to the left of the $x$-axis "cancels out" with everything to the right of the $x$-axis. However, you should walk through these steps to make sure you understand what's happening.

Now, for your problem. Let's call the function involved in your integral $f(x)$: so $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{1+x^2}$. Notice that for all $x$, $f(x) = -f(-x)$ (check this!). This means that your integral is of the form described above, with $o(x) = f(x)$ and $c = 1$. Therefore the answer is $0$.

Comment: Ahhh okay thank you!

Comment: If the answer solved your problem fully, make sure to press the "check" to accept it, so that other people browsing the site will know your question was answered to your satisfaction.